# Creating a vf page component to display user records on account

Tags: visualforce

I have a requirement to display user records ( with 4 fields) on Account page, where the User belongs(Account is a look up field on User object) to that particular account. How can we do this ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Example---- IF there are 5 User records, having " ABC" account, then the Account ABC, should display these 5 records on the Account. They do not want this as a related list, which is out of the box functionality.

Comment: What do you mean by "belongs"? What is the relationship between the account and the user?

Comment: Hi Aslam. User has an Account look up field.

Comment: I think this can be achieved by formula fields.

Comment: Cannot be done by formula User looks up to account, display on account. VF page can query for a list of users having that account ID then display the records / fields you want.

Comment: @user3303348 you can't create lookup to other objects from the standard User object. Have you created the relationship first? Unless you are referring to community users which will have an accountId field.

Comment: @Eric yeah I see that cannot be done via formula.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

1. Create a controller that queries the User records having that account ID
2. Create a VF page that uses the Account Standard Controller and the controller in #1 as an extension
3. Using Apex repeat, display the results of the query in the VF page
4. Place in the account page layout

Or use the related List component in the vf page as below answer suggests

Comment: Thanks Eric.In the controller, how can I take the Account ID, which I selected?

Comment: The documentation is huge for "related list". If I keep digging in more, of course I shall gain knowledge, but its gonna be time consuming

Comment: controller.getRecord().getId()

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must do this with Visualforce, I'd start with the standard `<apex:relatedList>` component.

[Here's a link to the documentation on `<apex:relatedList>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm)

+edit: After I looked into this some more, this solution probably isn't terribly useful in your situation.

In this case, the fields shown by `<apex:relatedList>` would be controlled by the User related list shown in the default page layout for the `recordType` of the Account record that your users are viewing.

In other words, to make `<apex:relatedLst>` show the 4 fields from the User object that you want to show, you'd need to put the related list on the same page layout that you'd be putting the visualforce page (that uses `<apex:relatedList>`) on...which defeats the purpose.

Eric's answer is the right one for your situation.

Comment: The documentation is huge for "related list". If I keep digging in more, of course I shall gain knowledge, but its gonna be time consuming